# I'm trying to get my website to display who's logged in, (i.e Hello Mike, or Welcome Mike) in PHP

Tags: php, html

as above when a user is logged into my website, I want it to say hello or welcome "user"

i'm using the code below:

```
 [code]      
 <?php
 $user = $_GET['session_is_registered'];
 echo ('$user'); 
 ?>
 [/code]
```

but the php just displays "$user"

what am I doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 5):

just use

```
echo $user;
```

echo is a keyword, not a function, so you don't need the parenthesis.  Also, to evaluate variables inside a string you need to use double quotation marks e.g. `echo "Hello, $user";`.  If you're just using the variable on its own you don't need the quotation marks at all.

```
echo $user;
echo 'Hello, ' . $user;
echo "Hello, $user.  Your last visit was $lastVisitDate.";
```

Answer (score 2):

Use double quotes if you want to evaluate `$user` variable inside a string. Otherwise just use:

```
echo $user;
```

As other answers have already stated.

Comment: Or use inline temp (http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/inlineTemp.html) to remove the temp variable "$user", possibly using curly braces to use the array reference within a double quoted string.

Answer (score 1):

When using ' single quotes, it means literal. You don't need any quotes.

```
 echo $user;
```

Thats it.